# How to extract text part from file using Python & Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing

Using Python I want to read a text file, search for a string and print all lines between this matching string and another one.

The textfile looks like the following:

```
Text=variables.Job_SalesDispatch.CaptionNew
    Tab=0
    TabAlign=0
    }
   }
  }
[UserVariables]
 User1=@StJid;IF(fields.Fieldtype="Artikel.Gerät"  , STR$(fields.id,0,0)  , @StJid)
[Parameters]
 [@Parameters]
  {
  [Parameters]
   {
   LL.ProjectDescription=? (default)
   LL.SortOrderID=
   }
  }
[PageLayouts]
 [@PageLayouts]
  {
  [PageLayouts]
   {
   [PageLayout]
    {
    DisplayName=
    Condition=Page() = 1
    SourceTray=0
```

Now I want to print all "UserVariables", so only the lines between `[UserVariables]` and the next line starting with a square bracket. In this example this would be `[Parameters]`.

What I have done so far is:

```py
with open("path/testfile.lst", encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as file:

  for line in file:
    uservars = re.findall('\b(\w*UserVariables\w*)\b', line)
    print (uservars)
```

what gives me only `[]`.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is
`User1=@StJid;IF(fields.Fieldtype="Artikel.Gerät"  , STR$(fields.id,0,0)  , @StJid)`in this example. But it is also possible to have more UserVariables like `User2=@StJid;IF(fields.Fieldtype="Artikel.Referenzgerät"  , STR$(fields.id,0,0)  , @StJid)`.

Answer (score 2):

If using regular expressions is not a mandatory requirement for you, you can go with something like this:

```py
with open("path/testfile.lst", encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as file:
  inside_uservars = False
  for line in file:
    if inside_uservars:
      if line.strip().startswith('['):
        inside_uservars = False
      else:
        print(line)
    if line.strip() == '[UserVariables]':
      inside_uservars = True
```

Comment: Thank you. That one is working for me. I will go through the code to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```
\[UserVariables\]\n((?:(?!\[.*?\]).)*)
```

This says to match a `[UserVariables]` tag, followed by a slightly complicated looking expression:

```
((?:(?!\[.*?\]).)*)
```

This expression is a *tempered dot* trick which matches any character, one at a time, so long as what lies immediately ahead is *not* another tag contained in square brackets.

```
matches = re.findall(r'\[UserVariables\]\n((?:(?!\[.*?\]).)*)', input, re.DOTALL)
print(matches)

[' User1=@StJid;IF(fields.Fieldtype="Artikel.Ger\xc3\xa4t"  , STR$(fields.id,0,0)  , @StJid)\n']
```

**Edit:**

My answer assumes that the entire file content sits in memory, in a single Python string.  You may read the entire file using:

```
with open('Path/to/your/file.txt', 'r') as content_file:
    input = content_file.read()
matches = re.findall(r'\[UserVariables\]\n((?:(?!\[.*?\]).)*)', input, re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

Comment: The RegEx-part is very cool and exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I am too dump to get it working in my code.

Comment: @Gardinero See my update.  My answer will only work if you read the entire file content into a single Python string.  Assuming your memory requirements/limitations would allow this, my answer should work, and is basically a one-liner.